# Fluent Nhibernate - How do I set the name attribute of a set or bag collection?

Tags: nhibernate, collections, fluent-nhibernate, set, bag

This is a set collection:

```
<set access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="employees" table="TeamEmployee" mutable="true">
```

How do I set the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fluently :-)

```
HasMany(x => x.SetName)
```

Comment: thanks Diego ... but how do I set a naming convention for this attribute?

Comment: The `name` attribute always corresponds to the property name. There's nothing you can customize there.